# Razor autocomplete doesen't work when submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, razor-pages

I'm having some problem with the autocomplete on my Razor project. Everytime it returns me error/failure. Maybe it could be even a stupid thing but I'm new to ASP so it would be difficult for me to notice.
Javascript Code

```
 $(function () {
    $('#searchCliente').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Index?handler=Search',
                data: { "term": request.term },
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return item;
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#idCliente").val(i.item.val);
            $("#idFatt").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 3
    });
});
```

Page Model Code

```
public IActionResult OnPostSearch(string term)
        {

            var clientefatt = (from cliente in this.context.Arc_Anagrafiche
                               where cliente.RagioneSociale.StartsWith(term)
                               select new
                               {
                                   label = cliente.RagioneSociale,
                                   val = cliente.IdAnag
                               }).ToList();

            return new JsonResult(clientefatt);
        }
```

HTML Code

```
<input asp-for="intervento.Cliente" class="form-control" id="searchCliente" />
<input asp-for="intervento.IdClienteFatturazione" class="form-control" id="idCliente" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: Please check my reply, whether the issue is related AddAntiforgery or not and whether it solved the problem? If the problem persists, try to use F12 developer tools to check if there has some JavaScript error?  If it solved the problem, I suggest you to try to mark it as an accepted answer for this question when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I'll check soon, beacuse for this week I've put aside this section of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is related to the AntiForgeryToken, try to add the XSRF-TOKEN property in the request header before sending the Ajax request.

Please refer to the following samples and modify your code:

1. Add AddAntiforgery() service in the ConfigureServices method:

   ```
    services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
   ```
2. In the Ajax beforeSend event, get the RequestVerificationToken from the hidden field, and set the request header:

   ```
    @page
    @model RazorPageSample.Pages.AutocompleteTestModel

    <form method="post">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="text" id="txtCustomer" name="label" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hfCustomer" name="val" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" asp-page-handler="Submit" />
        <br />
    </form> 
    @section Scripts{ 
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#txtCustomer").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/AutocompleteTest?handler=AutoComplete',
                            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                            },
                            data: { "prefix": request.term },
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                    return item;
                                }))
                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            },
                            failure: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    position: { collision: "flip" },
                    select: function (e, i) {
                        $("#hfCustomer").val(i.item.val);
                    },
                    minLength: 1
                });
            });
        </script>
    }
   ```

Code in the .cshtml.cs file:

```
    public IActionResult OnPostAutoComplete(string prefix)
    {
        var customers = new List<Customer>()
        {
            new Customer(){ ID=101, Name="Dillion"},
            new Customer(){ID=102, Name = "Tom"},
            new Customer(){ ID=103, Name="David"}
        }; 
        return new JsonResult(customers.Where(c=>c.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(prefix.ToLower())).Select(c=> new { label = c.Name, val = c.ID }).ToList());

    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, the screenshot as below:

[image]

Reference: [jQuery AutoComplete in ASP.Net Core Razor Pages](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-AutoComplete-in-ASPNet-Core-Razor-Pages.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shall assign the ajax datatype property, and also change the "type" property from post to get, as below:

```
            $.ajax({
            url: '/Index?handler=Search',
            data: { "term": request.term },
            datatype: 'json'
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return item;
                }))
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Also in the Model code you can try one of the following,

1. as when returning json the JSONRequestBehavior property shall be specified as AllowGet:

   ```
   return Json(new {clientefatt = clientefatt}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   ```
2. Change the Model code method's return type to JsonResult, as below

   ```
   public JsonResult OnPostSearch(string term){
    return new JsonResult(clientefatt);
   }
   ```

Most probably the first options, since you're using .net core, will give you an error "ASP.NET Core - The name 'JsonRequestBehavior' does not exist in the current context"